# Local volume not mount/bind with container while running IIS docker file [On Windows]

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**OS:Win 10 Pro**

**My IIS Docker file:**

```
FROM microsoft/iis:latest
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY content/ .
EXPOSE 80
```

**Build command:**

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo>docker build -t iis-image .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.656kB Step 1/5 : FROM microsoft/iis:latest
---> 248afbbe0fd1 Step 2/5 : RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot*
---> Using cache
---> 880273c74891 Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
---> Using cache
---> a07a920df3bf Step 4/5 : COPY content/ .
---> ab16da97c523 Step 5/5 : EXPOSE 80
---> Running in 98b7cbef83c9 Removing intermediate container 98b7cbef83c9
---> 1c7d232a73aa Successfully built 1c7d232a73aa Successfully tagged iis-image:latest
```

**Run Command:**

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo>docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo\content:/inetpub/wwwroot iis-image
```

**i also tried with:**

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo>docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\iis-demo\\content:/inetpub/wwwroot iis-image
```

**But everytime I am getting following error:**

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo\content:/inetpub/wwwroot'.
>       See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the missing trailing slash.

your code:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo>docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis- 
demo\content:/inetpub/wwwroot iis-image
```

is trying to load the folder `content` in the container
if its not there is will fail
try this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis-demo>docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis- 
demo\content\:/inetpub/wwwroot iis-image
```

or in your file make the directory `content`
and change your command to

```
 docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\iis- 
 demo\content:/inetpub/wwwroot/content iis-image
```

without the `/` you will add the directory 
with the `/` you add the contents of the directory to the container destination